# different drop down list for different nodes

Tags: nodes

I am using drupal 7.10.I have a content type bank details which is for entering bank details like bank name,address,contact details etc.,Now for each bank i need a drop down list which shows a list of agents of that particular bank.Note this is for each individual bank node.need help on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + [Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/references). Create new Views, that handle arguments of current node and filter agents by required bank.